# Apply concordance dataframe to zoo objects

Tags: r, zoo

I have a zoo object made of several time series, like this:

```
indices <- seq.Date(as.Date('2000-01-01'),as.Date('2005-01-30'),by="year")
a <- zoo(rnorm(5), order.by=indices)
b <- zoo(rnorm(5), order.by=indices)
c <- zoo(rnorm(5), order.by=indices)
ts_origin <- merge(a,b,c)
```

I would like to multiply each zoo series from ts_origin by a ratio contained in a dataframe, an put
the results in another zoo object (ts_final) that contains the time seris d,e,f. In other words,
the dataframe is a concordance file between a,b,c and d,e,f , and the ratio would be applied this way:
ts_final$d = ts_origin$a * 10 ; ts_final$e = ts_origin$b * 100 ; ts_final$f = ts_origin$c * 1000.

```
df <- data.frame(original = c("a","b","c"),
                 final = c("d","e","f"),
                 ratio = c(10,100,1000))


indices <- seq.Date(as.Date('2000-01-01'),as.Date('2005-01-30'),by="year")
d <- zoo(, order.by=indices)
e <- zoo(, order.by=indices)
f <- zoo(, order.by=indices)
ts_final <- merge(d,e,f)
```

Not too sure what the best approach for this. I was trying with the apply function, but couldn't make
it work... any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Map/merge**

Use `Map` to iterate over `final`, `original` and `ratio` executing the products required producing a list of zoo objects `L`.  Note that `Map` takes the names from the first argument after `fun`. Then merge the list components forming zoo object `ts_final`.

```
fun <- function(f, o, r) ts_origin[, o] * r
L <- with(df, Map(fun, final, original, ratio))
ts_final <- do.call("merge", L)
```

The result using the inputs shown in the Note at the end is this zoo object:

```
> ts_final
                    d          e          f
2000-01-01 -5.6047565   46.09162   400.7715
2001-01-01 -2.3017749 -126.50612   110.6827
2002-01-01 15.5870831  -68.68529  -555.8411
2003-01-01  0.7050839  -44.56620  1786.9131
2004-01-01  1.2928774  122.40818   497.8505
2005-01-01 17.1506499   35.98138 -1966.6172
```

**2) sweep**

Another approach is to `sweep` out the ratios setting the names appropriately giving the same result as in (1).

```
with(df, sweep(setNames(ts_origin[, original], final), 2, ratio, "*"))
```

**3) rep**

Set the names and multiply by ratio repeated appropriately giving the same result as in (1).

```
nr <- nrow(df)
with(df, setNames(ts_origin[, original], final) * rep(ratio, each = nr))
```

### Note

We can define the input reproducibly like this:

```
set.seed(123)
tt <- as.Date(ISOdate(2000:2005, 1, 1))
m <- matrix(rnorm(6*3), 6, dimnames = list(NULL, c("a", "b", "c")))
ts_origin <- zoo(m, tt)

df <- data.frame(original = c("a","b","c"),
                 final = c("d","e","f"),
                 ratio = c(10,100,1000))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner, with *wrong* final names.

```
ts_final <- t(df$ratio * t(ts_origin))

ts_final
#                   a         b          c
#2000-01-01 -5.382213 -12.64773  -513.6408
#2001-01-01 -9.218280 -98.55123 -1826.6430
#2002-01-01  2.114663 -28.58910   290.8008
#2003-01-01 -3.576460 -23.47314  -166.5473
#2004-01-01  6.490508 -36.29317  -398.0389
#2005-01-01 -5.382213 -12.64773  -513.6408
```

Now assign final names.

```
colnames(ts_final) <- df$final
```